# Symfony2 SonataMediaBundle Audio Config

Tags: symfony

I need to use SonataMediaBundle to store audio files - mp3 and maybe also somehow conwert them also to ogg.

So basically I need config.

Currently I have this:

```
sonata_media:
default_context: default
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
contexts:
    default:  # the default context is mandatory
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file

        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
    user:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.file
        formats:
            mp3: { quality: 100}
            ogg: { quality: 100}

cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/uploads/media
        create:     true
class:
    media:  Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
```

But when I Im using command:

php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\Radiooo\app\console sonata:media:add sonata.media.provider.file user C:/test.mp3

Im getting file stored like 45914671541816acb68412cc66ba1a71da3ac7a1.mpga

Can you help me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I made decision to write my bycicle based on this Sonata Managers, Providers and Generators...

Answer (score 2):

First of all: I'm totally aware of the creation date of this question, but I recently stumbled upon the same problem, where I wanted to upload a mp3 file and just keep the file extension to mp3 instead of switching it to mpga. And as far as I can see, there was no easy solution added to the source code in the last three years ...

I'm pretty sure that my solution is not the best one, but it does the job with a small amount of code to add :)

In my project, I had to upload a file by setting the `BinaryContent` of a `Media` object to the Symfony `Request` class, which leads the Problem to exactly this line:

```
// FileProvider.php#L483
$guesser = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance();
$extension = $guesser->guess($media->getContentType());
```

The `FileProvider` class fetches the instance of the `ExtensionGuesser` from Symfony and lets him do the work of guessing what the extension for the given ContentType should be:

```
// MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php#L623
'audio/mpeg' => 'mpga',
```

In my opinion it would be great, if we could either add own `MimeType->Extension` mappings or simply replace the class of the ExtensionGuesser with a small change in the configuration files. But no one knew that three people like us do not want to upload a mp3 file and switch the extension to mpga ... so there was no solution like these.

But we can actually change the className of the `FileProvider` and just overwrite the method that we want to do something different:

```
// app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    sonata.media.provider.file.class: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider



// Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider:
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Extra\ApiMediaFile;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\ExtensionGuesser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class FileProvider
 *
 * @package Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider
 */
class FileProvider extends \Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $contentTypeMapping = [
        'audio/mpeg' => 'mp3'
    ];

    /**
     * Set media binary content according to request content.
     *
     * @param MediaInterface $media
     */
    protected function generateBinaryFromRequest(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The current process cannot be executed in cli environment');
        }

        if (!$media->getContentType()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(
                'You must provide the content type value for your media before setting the binary content'
            );
        }

        $request = $media->getBinaryContent();

        if (!$request instanceof Request) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Expected Request in binary content');
        }

        $content   = $request->getContent();
        $extension = $this->getExtension($media->getContentType());

        $handle = tmpfile();
        fwrite($handle, $content);
        $file = new ApiMediaFile($handle);
        $file->setExtension($extension);
        $file->setMimetype($media->getContentType());

        $media->setBinaryContent($file);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the fileExtension for a given contentType
     *
     * First of all, we have to look at our own mapping and if we have no mapping defined, just use the ExtensionGuesser
     *
     * @param string $contentType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getExtension($contentType)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($contentType, $this->contentTypeMapping)) {
            return $this->contentTypeMapping[$contentType];
        }

        // create unique id for media reference
        $guesser   = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance();
        $extension = $guesser->guess($contentType);

        if (!$extension) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(
                sprintf('Unable to guess extension for content type %s', $contentType)
            );
        }

        return $extension;
    }
}
```

Until now it works pretty well and I had no problem with it :)